# How do I tell Visual Studio Code about the relative path

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am creating a react-app using the create-react-app tool so it uses webpack for module bundling. Having the following directory structure

```
-my-app
--node_modules
--src
---components
----somecomponent
-----SomeComponent.jsx
----someothercomponent
-----SomeOtherComponent.jsx
----main.js
----public
```

To avoid many `../../` (dot dot slashes for the relative path) I have set a `NODE_PATH=./src` as shown below in my package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_PATH=./src react-scripts start",
    "build": "NODE_PATH=./src react-scripts build",
}
```

So I can now import my modules in my like this

```
import SomeComponent from "/components/somecomponent/SomeComponent"
```

So even changing the directory structure will not break my code as often. But with this my VSCode doensn't recognise paths and thus doesn't show the intellisense, how do I fix it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I work on JS and TS support for VSCode. For this use case, I think you have a few options:

Create a `jsconfig.json` in the root of your project and use `baseUrl`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./src"
    }
}
```

This should allow for imports such as:

```
import SomeComponent from "components/somecomponent/SomeComponent"
```

Alternately, use the `paths` property:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "~/*": ["./src/*"]
        }
    }
}
```

this would allow imports of the form:

```
import SomeComponent from "~/components/somecomponent/SomeComponent"
```

You can find more details about these configuration options [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping)

Comment: I wish this worked for `.scss` files. There's probably a way, but it's murky