# Relative git path in VS Code settings

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have installed VS Code and git on a USB stick. The problem is that I need to set the `git.path` variable in VSCode settings, but it looks like I can't set a relative path : git is not found. Did I miss something? Is there a workaround?

VS Code executable path : `H:\Software\VSCode\Code.exe`

git executable path : `H:\Software\git\bin\git.exe`

How I tried to set the `git.path` variable in `settings.json` : `"git.path": "..\\git\\bin\\git.exe"`

Answer (score 0):

Use this formatting:

```
"git.path": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin",
```

or

```
"git.path": "\\Program Files\\Git\\bin",
```

I realize these arent relative but the latter option should be a relative *drive.*

Answer (score 0):

Based on the following post:
[How do I tell Visual Studio Code about the relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42856054/how-do-i-tell-visual-studio-code-about-the-relative-path)
I tried something like:

```json
"phpcs.executablePath": ".\\vendor\\bin\\phpcs",
```

for setting up PHP CodeSniffer in VS Code for the relative executable path for my project scoped PHPCS install and it worked!